# In neural networks, why conventionally set number of neurons to 2^n?

Tags: neural-network, conv-neural-network

For example, when pile up `Dense layers`, conventionally, we always set the number of neurons as 256 neurons, 128 neurons, 64 neurons, ... and so on.

My question is:

What's the reason for conventionally use `2^n` neurons? Will this implementation makes the code runs faster? Saves memory? Or are there any other reasons?

Comment: Then it looks more professional...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's historical. Early neural network implementations for GPU Computing (written in CUDA, OpenCL etc) had to concern themselves with efficient memory management to do data parallelism.

Generally speaking, you have to align N computations on physical processors. The number of physical processors is usually a power of 2. Therefore, if the number of computations is not a power of 2, the computations can't be mapped 1:1 and have to be moved around, requiring additional memory management (further reading [here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/20179/what-is-the-advantage-of-keeping-batch-size-a-power-of-2/20193)). This was only relevant for parallel batch processing, i.e. having the batch size as a power of 2 gave you slightly better performance. Interestingly, having other hyperparameters such as the number of hidden units as a power of 2 never had a measurable benefit - I assume as neural networks got more popular, people simply started adapting this practice without knowing why and spreading it to other hyperparameters.

Nowadays, some low-level implementations might still benefit from this convention but if you're using CUDA with Tensorflow or Pytorch in 2020 with a modern GPU architecture, you're very unlikely to encounter any difference between a batch size of 128 and 129 as these systems are highly optimized for very efficient data parallelism.

Comment: great explanation